# How to detect null value or no child values present in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have used Firebase [RecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) extensively in my app but since the below code doesn't fire populateViewHolder without any data to load in the first place, I can't show the load complete message for the initial load

```
RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_recycler);
recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(Chat.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ChatHolder.class, mRef) {
    @Override
    public void populateViewHolder(ChatHolder chatMessageViewHolder, Chat chatMessage, int position) {
        chatMessageViewHolder.setName(chatMessage.getName());
        chatMessageViewHolder.setText(chatMessage.getText());
    }
};
recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is covered by this feature: [Handle empty state for recycleview](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/118). You can handle this by implementing `onDataChanged()` in your adapter. A [snippet from the sample app of FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/e35c7d9162b9a1bea62c94258477ddc3982455ad/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/uidemo/database/ChatActivity.java#L163-L166):

```
@Override
protected void onDataChanged() {
    // if there are no chat messages, show a view that invites the user to add a message
    mEmptyListView.setVisibility(
        mRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if(chatMessage.getName().equals("")){   //null value    }else{
>   //execute code }

Comment: If the complete node is empty it doesn't trigger in the first place.., so the above solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Override onDataChanged() and check in it

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(Chat.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ChatHolder.class, mRef) {
    @Override
    public void populateViewHolder(ChatHolder chatMessageViewHolder, Chat chatMessage, int position) {
        chatMessageViewHolder.setName(chatMessage.getName());
        chatMessageViewHolder.setText(chatMessage.getText());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDataChanged() {
    // do your tests here
    }
};
```